# Need help setting up Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine

i setup Doctrine 1 b4 but it seems like now when i try Doctrine 2 it fails

i have Doctrine installed at `D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine`

```
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\bin
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\Doctrine
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\Doctrine\Common
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\Doctrine\DBAL
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\Doctrine\ORM
```

i put `D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\bin` in the `PATH` Windows Environment Variable
and added `D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine` to the php.ini `include_path`

i find that when i try to do

```
D:\>php doctrine.php
Could not open input file: doctrine.php
```

fails ... i thought that since i have `D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\bin` in the `PATH` Windows Environment Variable, it shld be able to find `doctrine.php`?

```
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\bin>php doctrine.php

Warning: require(D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\bin/../lib/vendor\Symfony\Components\Console\Helper\HelperSet.ph
p): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoad
er.php on line 143

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\bin/../lib/vendor\Symfony\Compon
ents\Console\Helper\HelperSet.php' (include_path='D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library;D:\ResourceLibrary
\Frameworks\Doctrine;.;c:\php\includes') in D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php on li
ne 143
```

then 2nd try, pass with errors ...

Comment: `PATH` is just used to find the command (`php` in your case), not to resolve filenames passed to the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the entire Symfony framework. Just the bits that Doctrine relies on.

If you download the [current version](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/download) of the ORM component (right now at BETA2), it will include a folder called `Symfony` (probably  in `lib/vendor/Symfony`, but it tends to move around with new releases). You need to make sure that the ClassLoader in `doctrine.php` or `cli-config.php` can find that Symfony folder.

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', __DIR__ . '/path/to/Symfony');
$classLoader->register();
```

I hope this information is accurate. The Doctrine team keeps messing with the structure of the release they closer they get to a final version.

Comment: yes something like this does the trick. i need to replace `__DIR__ . '/path/to/Symfony'` to `D:/ResourceLibrary/Frameworks/Symfony` same for doctrine `D:/ResourceLibrary/Frameworks/Doctrine`. question is php `include_path` does not seem to do anything here?

Comment: include_path will help load files if you're using 'require'. For auto-loading classes by name, you need to spl_autoloader, or something like Doctrine's ClassLoader or Zend_Loader_Autoloader.

Comment: i found that i can also omit the `/path/to/symfony` all that if i have `include_path`set

Answer (score 6):

After spending several hours to configure Doctrine 2 on my machine last night I finally succedded to work with Doctrine 2.

I configured Doctrine 2 in this way.

There are several ways to install Doctrine 2 although I preferred to download from package manager.

First I downloaded package DoctrineORM-2.0.0BETA3.tgz from http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/download

I extracted the tar file inside my test folder where I tested my sample code. My folder looks like

```
./test
DoctrineORM/
DoctrineORM/bin
DoctrineORM/bin/Doctrine
```

Then I created 2 folders on root 'model' and 'proxies'.

Now we need to bootstrap Doctrine.

```
--- Bootsrap ---
<?php
//    test.php

require 'DoctrineORM/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', 'DoctrineORM');
$classLoader->register(); // register on SPL autoload stack

$classloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('model', __DIR__);
$classloader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('model');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setProxyDir('proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('proxies');

$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
$config->getAutoGenerateProxyClasses();

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname' => 'test',
    'user' => '[DB_User]',
    'password' => '[DB_Pass]'
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
//echo 'Hello World!' . PHP_EOL;

//    Get result from Table
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM model\User c ORDER BY c.name');
$t = $q->getResult();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($t);

//    Save a new User to DB
$uu = new model\User();
$uu->name = 'test name1';
$uu->age = 4;
$em->persist($uu);
$em->flush();    
--- Bootsrap ---
```

Then I created a model file in model directory

```
--- Model - User.php ---
<?php
//    Model File model/User.php 
namespace Model;

/** @Entity @Table(name="users") */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public     $id;
    /** @Column(type="string", length=50) */
    public     $name;
    /** @Column(type="integer", length=50) */
    public $age;
}
--- Model - User.php ---
```

My complete folder structure now looks like below.

```
./test
DoctrineORM/
DoctrineORM/bin
DoctrineORM/bin/Doctrine

Model/
Model/User.php
test.php
```

Hope this will help you. If you need any further help I can send you the complete source which works fine at my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the command line interface in the new Doctrine 2 beta you also have to install the Symfony 2 framework (because it includes the Console Helper) and put it into your include path.

As far as I know there is currently no PEAR installation available, so you will have to download the sources from the [Symfony 2 website](http://symfony-reloaded.org/) or via Git.

**On a sidenote:** It seems that you also tried to execute doctrine.php at a path where it doesn’t exist. That’s the reason why you got the

> Could not open input file: doctrine.php

error message.

Comment: ok so now how do i install Symfony? what path do i add to my include path? i have `D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Symfony` in my include_path and in that folders `Symfony\Bundle`, `Symfony\Components` & `Symfony\Framework`. i am getting the same error ...

Comment: One easy hack for the beta would be to put the Symfony folder in your main PEAR folder. You wouldn't have to mess around with class loaders. If PEAR is set up correctly on your system everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine v2.* is stored in bin dir.

Try like this :

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:conver-mapping xml src/ --from-database --force
```

Dont put PHP on start.